# Two Players Fighting With Multiple Attack Options Java

Tags: java

I am trying to create a game where there is two fighters. A warrior versus gladiator. 
Both of the fighters have 1000 health. When the battle starts, player 1 gets to choose between three options: 1 - thrust 2 - slice 3 - drink potion...

Lets say player 1 chooses thrust and attacks 55 (using random) then my code prints player 2's new health which is now 945. Then it's player two's turn and lets say he does the exact same thing and takes off some health from player 1.

Now it will go back to player 1's turn. This is where it gets complicated. Now player 1 attacks for the second time and lets say he does 80 damage. It will print out that player two has 920 health. It doesn't have the previous attack subtracted off. I want them to fight until one of there health goes down to 0 and dies.

So how can I fix my code so the health doesn't restart at 1000 after each attack and it subtracts from the new health that was already been lowered from the previous attacks. Like this: 1000 hp - 55 = 945 hp - 80 = 865 hp etc. I' new to coding. Started in January. Any help would be amazing!

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Duel 
{
Random hit = new Random();
Random hit1 = new Random();

int newHealth, newHealth1;
int outcome, outcome1, outcome2, outcome3;
int attack, attack1;
int defense, defense1;
int health, health1;

void calculateWinner()
{
  do
  { 
     outcome = hit1.nextInt(100) - hit1.nextInt(15);
     newHealth1 = health1 - outcome;

     System.out.println("Your attack does " + outcome + " damage!");
     System.out.println("");
     System.out.print("Warrior Health: " + newHealth1 + "\n");
     break;
  }     

  while(newHealth1 == 0);
  //System.out.println("Gladiator is the winner!");

}

void calculateWinner1()
{
  do
  { 
     outcome1 = hit.nextInt(100) - hit.nextInt(15);
     newHealth = health - outcome1;

     System.out.println("Your attack does " + outcome1 + " damage!");
     System.out.println("");
     System.out.print("Gladiator Health: " + newHealth + "\n\n");
     break;
  }     

  while(newHealth == 0);
  //System.out.println("Warrior is the winner!");
}

void calculateHealth()
{
  do
  { 
     newHealth = health + hit.nextInt(35);
     System.out.println("You drink the potion.");
     System.out.println("Your health is now at " + newHealth + "!");
     break;
  }     

  while(newHealth1 > 0 && newHealth > 0);
}

 void calculateHealth1()
{
  do
  { 
     newHealth1 = health1 + hit.nextInt(35);
     System.out.println("You drink the potion.");
     System.out.println("Your health is now at " + newHealth1 + "!");
     break;
  }     

  while(newHealth1 > 0 && newHealth > 0);
}
}


import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DuelMain 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  // Random + Scanner
  Random hit = new Random();
  Random hit1 = new Random();
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  // String + Int
  String player1name = "";
  String player2name = "";
  int restart;
  int player1option;
  int player2option;
  int fight = 0;

  Duel warrior = new Duel();
  Duel gladiator = new Duel();

  gladiator.attack = hit.nextInt(100);
  gladiator.defense = hit.nextInt(15);
  gladiator.health = 1000;

  warrior.attack1 = hit1.nextInt(100);
  warrior.defense1 = hit1.nextInt(15);;
  warrior.health1 = 1000;

  // Printing Names
  System.out.print("Gladiator Enter Name: ");
  player1name = input.nextLine();

  System.out.print("Warrior Enter Name: ");
  player2name = input.nextLine();

  while(fight == 0)
  {
     // Choose Moves (Player1)
     System.out.printf("%n%s, Choose Your Move! \n", player1name);
     System.out.println("1: Thrust 2: Slice 3: Drink Potion");
     player1option = input.nextInt();

     if(player1option == 1)
     {
        System.out.printf("You Thrust Your Sword At %s! \n", player2name);

        warrior.attack1 = hit1.nextInt(100);
        warrior.defense1 = hit1.nextInt(15);
        warrior.health1 = 1000;
        warrior.calculateWinner();
     }

     if(player1option == 2)
     {
        System.out.printf("You Slice Your Sword At %s! \n", player2name);

        warrior.attack1 = hit1.nextInt(100);
        warrior.defense1 = hit1.nextInt(15);
        warrior.health1 = 1000;
        warrior.calculateWinner();
     }

     if(player1option == 3)
     {
        warrior.calculateHealth();
     }

     // Choose Moves (Player2)
     System.out.printf("%n%s, Choose Your Move! \n", player2name);
     System.out.println("1: Thrust 2: Slice 3: Drink Potion");
     player2option = input.nextInt();

     if(player2option == 1)
     {
        System.out.printf("You Thrust Your Sword At %s! \n", player1name);

        gladiator.attack = hit.nextInt(100);
        gladiator.defense = hit.nextInt(15);
        gladiator.health = 1000;
        gladiator.calculateWinner1();
     }

     if(player2option == 2)
     {
        System.out.printf("You Slice Your Sword At %s! \n", player1name);

        gladiator.attack = hit.nextInt(100);
        gladiator.defense = hit.nextInt(15);
        gladiator.health = 1000;
        gladiator.calculateWinner1();;
     }

     if(player2option == 3)
     {
        gladiator.calculateHealth1();
     }
  }        
}
}
```

Comment: Removing `security` tag considering the question has absolutely nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Within the blocks after `if(playerXoption == N)`, you are resetting the character health to 1000 with `warrior.health1 = 1000` and `gladiator.health = 1000`.  Removing those lines should allow health to continue to be degraded by further attacks without being reset.

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to point you in any direction, but I highly suggest you read java and objective oriented progaming tutorials again. Anyhow, I'll try to make it short.

First of all, you need a class for your warriors. Every warrior will be an instance of this class. Each of them will have attributes: health, damage and defense (let's say the damage is going to be constant at the moment).

```
public class Warrior {
public Warrior(final int health, final int damage, final int defense) {
    this.health = health;
    this.damage = damage;
    this.defense = defense;
}

public int getHealth() {
    return health;
}

public void setHealth(int health) {
    this.health = health;
}

public int getDamage() {
    return damage;
}

public void setDamage(int damage) {
    this.damage = damage;
}

public int getDefense() {
    return defense;
}

public void setDefense(int defense) {
    this.defense = defense;
}

private int health;
private int damage;
private int defense;
```

}

Then we need a class that will handle the duel. To keep things simple it will be pretty hard-coded. Basically it'll just make two warriors that will smack each other until one drops dead.

```
public class Duel {
private Warrior warrior;
private Warrior gladiator;

public Duel() {
    warrior = new Warrior(1000, 100, 20);
    gladiator = new Warrior(1000, 80, 30);
}

public int doDuel() {
    while (true) {
        if (attack(warrior, gladiator)) {
            return 1;
        } else if (attack(gladiator, warrior)) {
            return 2;
        }
    }
}        

public boolean attack(final Warrior attacker, final Warrior defender) {
    defender.setHealth(defender.getHealth() - (attacker.getDamage() - defender.getDefense()));
    if (defender.getHealth() <= 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

In main call:

```
final Duel duel = new Duel();
if(duel.doDuel() == 1) {
    // warrior won
} else {
   //  gladiator won
}
```

Have in mind it's very naive and simple implementation. There are milions of ways to implement something like this.